# Is there a shortkey in eclipse to launch (favorite) external application e.g. parameterized maven build?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

*Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective > Toolbar visibility > Launch* includes the elements "Debug" and "Run", these are active in my toolbar.

Through the toolbar I have set favorites with "Organize favorites..." for *Debug* (Java application with parameters) and *Run* (maven build with parameters).

Now I am searching for a way to access/start these without using the mouse. Reaching the toolbar with tabbing through all elements seems incredibly hard and I can't find an entry in *Window > Preferences > General > Key*.

Comment: Launch conffigurations are also available via _Find Actions_, formerly _Quick Access_, (Ctrl+3) [since Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/platform.php#launch-config-quickaccess).

Comment: Actually I'd like accept this comment as answer, I can enter the name of the run configuration directly into the Quick Access, which is very handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way to start a *Run* or *Debug launch* with keys is to use the *Quick Access* (Ctrl+3) described in howlgers comment (thanks a lot!).

In there you simply type the defined name of the launch you'd like to start, alternatively you can write `Debug` or `Run` to list all launches available.